# Nested IF Statements In Excel or a better formula

Tags: excel

I am writing a formula in excel, where my current IF statement is doing what if statements are supposed to do but I am need different results and its pulling right for some of them and for some they are not what i want. I tried playing around with them but didn't find a better way to do. If any one can please help me on this.

[image]

Formula I used to get Column E

```
=IF(D2*1.2>B2,D2*1.2,IF(D2*1.2<B2,B2-1,IF(B2*1.2<4,B2*1.2+4,B2*1.2)))
```

I know IF statements executes sequentially but I need Column F as required output. Or we can use any other formula which i am not aware of.

Thanks,
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why to you have two rows for Producct `A5`

Comment: Your logic is unclear. And your example of your desired results does not indicate how you expect to obtain those results. In particular,few of the IF formulas in Column E will produce the desired result with the given data.